# How to check for undefined variable property in HTL (AEM)?

Tags: aem, sightly, htl

Newbie to AEM here. 
Say I have:

```
<div
     data-text="${myVariable.someProperty}"
     ...
```

I do not wish to have data-text to return a `"undefined"` string if it is undefined. I tried using the logical operator and it didn't work..

```
<div
     data-text="${myVariable.someProperty ? myVariable.someProperty : ''}"
```

I supposed that `myVariable.someProperty` returns undefined instead of a boolean value. Any ideas how I can check for undefined in HTL (or am I doing something completely wrong)?

Comment: you can try this myVariable.someProperty == 'undefined' ?  '' :  myVariable.someProperty

Comment: Do you want to have `data-text` attribute but with empty string value? Sightly removes the attributes with blank value from markup. Also if you can add details about `myVariable` is that being returned from JS or Java use API?

Comment: Where and how is that property set? HTL expressions do not output anything for undefined values. Having `undefined` rendered indicates that the property was already set to the `"undefined"` string value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTL will not render anything for undefined values. Assuming an JS use-object:

**logic.js:**

```
use(function () {
    return {
        test: undefined
    };
});
```

and an **HTL script:**

```
<div data-sly-use.logic="logic.js" data-text="${logic.test}"></div>
```

the output will be:

```
<div></div>
```

The attribute is stripped as it is falsy (see [attributes detailed examples](https://github.com/Adobe-Marketing-Cloud/htl-spec/blob/master/SPECIFICATION.md#2231-detailed-examples)). If you want to keep the attribute you might want to modify the HTL expression to `${logic.test || true}`.

If you modify your use-object to return an `'undefined'` string:

```
use(function () {
    return {
        test: 'undefined'
    };
});
```

then you get the following output:

```
<div data-text="undefined"></div>
```

In this case you might want to modify your expression to test for the `'undefined'` string: `${logic.test == 'undefined' ? '': logic.test}`. Again, you can keep the attribute by replacing `''` with `true`.

Comment: I have java in my backend

Comment: You can still have this js parallel to your htl and use it

Answer (score 1):

According to the HTL [documentation](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/htl/using/expression-language.html)

> ... *operators* are typically used with Boolean values, however, like in JavaScript, they actually return the value of one of the specified operands, so when used with non-Boolean values, they may return a non-Boolean value
>
> If a value can be converted to *false*, the value is so-called *falsy*. Values that can be converted to false are: *undefined* variables, *null* values, the number *zero*, and *empty* strings.

Conforming to it, `data-sly-test="${myVariable.someProperty == true}"` should do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the other provided solutions there is another way to achieve something like this, even though it might seem a bit counter intuitive and verbose:

```
<!-- Only show this div if "someProperty" is set -->
<div data-text="${myVariable.someProperty}" 
     data-sly-test.hasValue="${myVariable.someProperty}">

<!-- Show alternative div if "someProperty" is not set -->
<div data-text="No value defined" data-sly-test="!hasValue">
```

The code above is basically a `if - else` statement. Only one of the `div` elements will be displayed. Which one depends on `someProperty`being set or not.

Note that the result of `data-sly-test` is stored in `hasValue` so that test does not have to be repeated for the second `div`.

Answer (score 0):

Above solution from jens is correct but there is a syntax error in the usage of hasValue variable.

```
<div data-text="No value defined" data-sly-test="${!hasValue}">
```

Answer (score 0):

`data-sly-test="${myVariable.someProperty !=null}"` as simple as that can do the job. It checks if the property is present and returns "true" or "false"